High CPU Usage Process by postgres
I have a Nodejs app that is always running and updates data. when starting, the app gets history data and bulkInsert it into psql(about 400 in each query)
then it gets live data from redis and every minute, insert the new data into psql.
After a while that my app is running, a process by postgres user is on 100% cpu usage. the COMMAND shows a number(10 for example) and even when i kill it, it just spawns another process again.
even when the app is stopped, that process is running.
I had to delete the postgres user or clean the server to stop that process. but when i started my app, after a while it happened again.
Im using pg-promise for psql and ioredis for redis.
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1623 postgres  20   0 2456628   2.3g      8 S 398.7  29.7   9:57.75 10
htop result
My Bulk Insert Function
const insertBulkRecordsQuery = async (tableName: string, symbolName: string, data: HistoryData): Promise<string> => { try { const { t, c, h, l, o, v } = data;

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet( ['symbol_name', 'open_time', 'open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'close_price', 'volume', 'created_at'], table: tableName }
        );

const records = t.map((_, i) => 
({ 
symbol_name: symbolName, 
open_time: t[i], 
open_price: o[i], 
high_price: h[i], 
low_price: l[i], 
close_price: c[i], 
volume: v[i], 
created_at: new Date(Number(t[i]) * 1000)
}));

const query = pgp.helpers.insert(records, cs); 
return query 
catch (error) { console.error("Error creating bulk insert: ", error); throw error;
    } };

My Insert
const insertRecordQuery = (tableName: string, symbolName: string, record: any): { query: string, values: any[] } => { const { t, c, h, l, o, v } = record;

const query =
 ` INSERT INTO ${tableName} 
(symbol_name, open_time, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, volume, created_at) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, NOW()); `;

const values = [symbolName, t, o, h, l, c, v];

return { query, values}; 
};

I also have a query to get that history data each 5 second
async function getCandleData(symbolNames: string[], tableName: string): Promise<CandleData[]> { 
try { 
const query = 
`SELECT * FROM ${tableName} 
WHERE symbol_name IN ($1:csv) 
ORDER BY open_time DESC 
LIMIT ${400 * symbolNames.length}
`;

const data: CandleData[] = await db.any(query, [symbolNames]);

return data; 

catch (error) { throw new Error(`Error retrieving candle data: ${error}`);
    } }

is the problem with my app or its something else im missing?
Stopping the app, stopping psql, killing the proccess, but none worked.

Please post code inside actual code block and not in quotation block

@Justinas sorry, fixed it.

That doesn't appear to be a postgresql command. I'd assume you've been hacked.

Hackers mining crypto currency on your CPUs. If you must allow connections from the Internet, use good passwords.

symbol_name IN ($1:csv) -- that's a performance killer. How many symbols are you using inthe IN clause?

Use EXPLAIN to analyze performance.

What's the complete command for -c/tmp/... ? What does it do?

@FrankHeikens i have no idea. top shows the command as a number(once 10, after i killed it, respawned with 23)
i think its a folder but i dont know what it does

@TheImpaler lots of symbols. but even when the app is stopped, that process is there and running.

Most likely you have been hacked. Turn off your network connection, activate the firewall, and get some virus detection and cleaning program to clean up your computer.
